# Unable to get IIS Express server running in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, iis-express, vstest

I'm trying to run Selenium tests utilizing an `IISExpress` server. I'm using the VSTest plugin to run my tests. Everything works fine locally in Visual Studio but when I run the tests in Jenkins the `IISExpress` process never starts. I even tried adding a Windows Batch Command step in Jenkins specifically for loading up the server, but even that doesn't seem to do anything. When I run Jenkins as a service that can interact with the desktop and I watch what its doing, I can see that Selenium loads up the browser but `IISExpress` just never starts. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: One additional note: the output of trying to run IISExpress is as follows:

Filename: redirection.config
Error: Cannot read configuration file

Comment: And again, if I just run IISExpress via command line it works FINE!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to launch IIS Express through command prompt by either

Explicitly providing the /path:"@PATH" and /port:"@PORT" command line arguments, and then invoking an asynchronous call to the IIS Express executable.

Your command in Jenkins should be something along the lines of:

```
start "YOUR_IIS_EXPRESS_EXE" /path:"PATH_TO_YOUR_APPLICATION" /port:"YOUR_APPLICATION_PORT"
```

Or by

Providing a value for the /config command line argument.
Whilst using this technique however, ensure that your application is the first entry in the application host.config file.

The Jenkins command should then be something similar to:

```
start "YOUR_IIS_EXPRESS_EXE" /config:"PATH_TO_YOUR_APPLICATIONHOST.CONFIG_FILE"
```

Comment: Yeah, but is it a good solution for Jenkins?
A. IIS Express can't run multiple instances, so only one build at a time
B. What if the test execution fail? You have to shutdown the server, and that step might not execute...